# Links are not working in Sortable container (in Android )

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

In the image below is my sortable container and individual image can be dragged and dropped to sort. But the action links(icons) in the box are not working on the android browser because of the Js. When I remove sortable JS the links work fine. How can I make both of them work together?

[image]

Sortable Js

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
            cursor: "move",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var id = ui.item.attr("id");
                var PropID = $("#PropID").html();
                var obj = {
                    PropID: PropID,
                    ID: id,
                    Pos1: ui.item.startPos ? ui.item.startPos : 0,
                    Pos2: ui.item.index() ? ui.item.index() : 0
                }
                try {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/members/pm-add-photos.aspx/MovePhoto",
                        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            var result = msg.d;
                            if (result.toLowerCase().indexOf('error') > -1) {
                                triggertoast("", "We're sorry, there seems to have been an error.", "error");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                    });

                }
                catch (err) {
                    triggertoast("", "We're sorry, there seems to have been an error.", "error");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+android+sortable+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.